# didn't update the dropdownlist changed value asp.net C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to take the drop down list's selected value to update another drop down list. data binding is working. but the "ddl1"'s selected value not change when selecting an item. therefore "ddl1.SelectedValue" notworkin correctly

Please check this code & help me to correct it

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string selectmap = "select [id]+' - '+[title] as title, id from map order by id;";
    SqlDataAdapter comm = new SqlDataAdapter(selectmap, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    comm.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();
    ddl1.DataSource = dt;

    ddl1.DataTextField = "title";
    ddl1.DataValueField = "id";
    ddl1.DataBind();
    ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---- Select Map ----", "0"));
    Label2.Text = ddl1.SelectedIndex.ToString();



protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string selectmap2 = "select [id]+' - '+[title] as title, id from map where id !='"+ddl1.SelectedValue+"' order by id;";
    SqlDataAdapter comm2 = new SqlDataAdapter(selectmap2, conn);
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    comm2.Fill(dt2);
    ddl2.DataSource = dt2;

    ddl2.DataTextField = "title";
    ddl2.DataValueField = "id";
    ddl2.DataBind();
    ddl2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---- Select Map ----", "0"));
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Where is the other dropdownlist?

Comment: We need the markup for both dropdownlists and code for both event handlers.

Comment: updated the code

Comment: Where is the markup and event handler for the second dropdownlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Populateddl1();
        }
    }
    private void Populateddl1()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string selectmap = "select [id]+' - '+[title] as title, id from map order by id;";
        SqlDataAdapter comm = new SqlDataAdapter(selectmap, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        comm.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        ddl1.DataSource = dt;

        ddl1.DataTextField = "title";
        ddl1.DataValueField = "id";
        ddl1.DataBind();
        ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---- Select Map ----", "0"));

    }

    protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Write here for populating second dropdown code
    }
```

Comment: I did. Its work. But the thing is ddl1.SelectedValue not changed.